# How does retention time is applied in kafka aggregate state store topics?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I just got confused about the calculation of the retention time (retention.ms) of the state store topic in aggregate function of streams.

here is stream configuration for building the topology:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "appId1");
    props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
    props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.WINDOW_STORE_CHANGE_LOG_ADDITIONAL_RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(5));

    props.put(StreamsConfig.topicPrefix(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG), 200);
```

additional retention is set to **5**
topic retention is set to **200**

Assume that I have this code for creating topology: (to just going simple, I'm not doing anything in aggregate function, I just want to state store topic to be built)
without windowing

```
    //topology1
    final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> source = streamsBuilder.stream("test-topic");
    source.groupByKey().aggregate(() -> "1",  (key, value, aggregate) -> "2");
```

Topology1 will create state store topic with **retention.ms=200**
Here retention is 200 (default topic retention)

windowing :

```
    //topology2
    final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> source = streamsBuilder.stream("test-topic");
    source.groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(10)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(1)))
            .aggregate(() -> "1", (key, value, aggregate) -> "2");
```

Topology2 will create state store topic with **retention.ms=86400005**
Here retention is 86400000 **(???)** + 5 (additional retention)

windowing by setting retention :

```
    //topology3
    final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> source = streamsBuilder.stream("test-topic");
    source.groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(10)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(1)))
            .aggregate(() -> "1",  (key, value, aggregate) -> "2"
                    , Materialized.<String, String, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("agg")
                            .withRetention(Duration.ofMillis(300)));
```

Topology3 will create state store topic with **retention.ms=305**
Here retention is 300(explicit retention set) + 5 (additional retention)

To run the application this code is also required:

```
    Topology topology = streamsBuilder.build();
    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
    streams.start();
```

**So, what is the logic behind setting topics retention in the topology state store topics?

Why in Topology1 additional retention is not used?

Why in Topology2, default topic retention is not used?

In Topology2, what parameter is 86400000 that is summed up with additional retention?

Finally, additional retention is not used in Topology1 but used in Topology3 where retention is explicitly set.**

Can anyone explain the logic behind these?

Comment: I think that when you have the window time less than the retention time your window will collect values only based on the retention time. In other words, the window time must be greater than the retention time, since the retention time is the timw when KTable emits data.

Answer (score 0):

For windowed KStreams, there is a local retention time having default value of 24h or 86400000ms.. Hence the reason behind Topology2 retention time.

You can set the local store retention time via `Materialized.withRetentionTime(...)`, which is why Topology3 retention time is 305ms

Comment: This is actually what I described. What is the `local retention time` parameter and how could I set it manually?